# Azure Functions. Debugging java from VS Code. Can not connect to a debugee VM

Tags: java, azure, debugging, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

did anyone faced with such problem. Have an Azure Functions app (beta-2 plugin version used). After app started I receive an error that VSCode failed attach to remove debuggee VM. Reason: Connection Refused.

I have VSCode with the following plugins installed: ms-azuretools.vscode-azurefunctions,  vscjava.vscode-java-debug, vscjava.vscode-java-pack, vscjava.vscode-maven, redhat.java

launch.json contains following configuration:

```
`{
    "name": "Attach to Java Functions",
    "type": "java",
    "request": "attach",
    "hostName": "localhost",
    "port": 5005,
    "preLaunchTask": "runFunctionsHost"
}`
```

runFunctionsHost contains following script:
`mvn clean package -B; func host start --debug VSCode --script-root ....`

OS: windows

Comment: If you look at your terminal output, does it say "Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005" once the functions runtime starts?

Comment: Nope, nothing like that :-(

Comment: ok, found out an issue. Added "JAVA_OPTS" : "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=127.0.0.1:5005" into local.settings.json

Comment: Igor, did that fix your issue?

Comment: yep, JAVA_OPTS has did the trick

Comment: @IgorGnedysh Great, you could post it as an answer and mark it for others to refer.

Comment: yep, have done it. thanks that mentioned this :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions is to add "JAVA_OPTS" parameter into the local.settings.json with the value like that "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=127.0.0.1:5005"

Comment: where should I add this parameter? Couldn't find the local.settings.json file or do you mean launch.json?

Comment: Didn't work to me, tried in both jsons. I Intelij was working without that error.

Comment: Actual formatted code would be helpful here for us to see explicitly what the json would look like...

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best way but it solves the problem

1. launch from console manually with debug option:

mvn package azure-functions:run -DenableDebug

this makes function to listen to 5005 port for debugging

2. Attach the VSCode debugger to the port

Launch the folling launch configuration

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Attach to Java Functions",
        "type": "java",
        "request": "attach",
        "hostName": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 5005
    }
]
```

}

This would allow you to debug from VSCode.

Clues obtained from IntelliJ solution, is kinda the same procedure: https://blog.mimacom.com/implementing-azure-functions-with-java/